# How to add a menu item to the default right-click on the devexpress treelist

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a DevExpress (version 9.2) TreeList that by default displays a menu containing sort ascending/descending, column chooser, and best fit when you right-click on the header of the tree.

How would I add more choices to this default menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the default menu you need to use the ShowTreeListMenu action listener and add the rows in there.

```
  Private Sub treeCompany_ShowTreeListMenu(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeListMenuEventArgs) Handles treeCompany.ShowTreeListMenu
       ' add the ability to expand the nodes in the tree
        e.Menu.Items.Add(New DevExpress.Utils.Menu.DXMenuItem("Expand All Nodes", AddressOf ExpandNode))
       ' make the last item added begin the group so you have a divider
        e.Menu.Items(e.Menu.Items.Count - 1).BeginGroup = True
       ' add the ability to collapse the nodes in the tree
        e.Menu.Items.Add(New DevExpress.Utils.Menu.DXMenuItem("Collapse All Nodes", AddressOf CollapseAll))
  End Sub
```

The first addition calls the function `ExpandNode()` and the second  calls `CollapseAll()`.

Comment: This is the way to go with DevExpress v9.xx

Answer (score 1):

```
    void treeList1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DXMenuItem item = new DXMenuItem("New menu item");
        e.Menu.Items.Add(item);


    }
```

Or do the menu item add in the form load event handler. Add a menu click handler as needed.

Comment: I don't see that as an object under the properties of the treelist. The only action under "p" are PaddingChanged, ParentChanged and PreviewKeyDown.

Comment: I'm using v10.2, perhaps it's new. It's also not documented anywhere. I can find no other way to influence the menu actually. Maybe you have PreparePopupMenu and can use that.